# TextBox in Gridview return null or 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, textbox

I have a problem with retrieving of data from textbox. TextBox is located in Gridview. I tried to debug and it showed that my variable where I collect a value of textbox returns `null` or `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`.

Could you please help me to figurr out what the problem is?

Here is the code from back-end and gridview

```
public void Button_Submit_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //Textbox from Gridview
        TextBox txt_field = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[12].FindControl("txt_Comment");
        //Connection string
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDeductionsConnectionString2"].ToString();
        //id of column
        int recordid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[i].Values[0]);
        //checkbox value
        CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox)GridView2.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        bool private1 = Convert.ToBoolean(cbox.Checked); 
        //open connection and creating sqlcommand
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "Update DetailCosts set private='" + private1 + "' Komentar='" + txt_field + "'  where recordid=" + recordid;
        //
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@private1", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = private1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recordid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = recordid.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Komentar", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txt_field.ToString();               
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (private1==true)
        {
            //DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            //cmd.CommandText = "Update AprovedCosts set AprovedCosts.AprovalUser = ";

            cmd.CommandText = "Update DetailCosts set privateCost=Costs where recordid=" + recordid;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "Update DetailCosts set privateCost=0 where recordid=" + recordid;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Comment" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Komentar") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more simple just use it like this

```
TextBox txt_field = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[12].FindControl("txt_Comment");
string txt = txt_field.text; //store it's text in string
```

and change `command`

in place of `txt_field` just write txt or `txt.ToString();`

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Update DetailCosts set private='" + private1 + "' Komentar='" + txt + "'  where recordid=" + recordid;
    //
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@private1", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = private1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recordid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = recordid.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Komentar", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `txt_field.Text` instead of `txt_field.ToString()` to get the value.

Comment: but System.Web.UI.Control doesn't consist of Text method, i can't use it

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a control that **could possibly not exist** and assigning it to a textbox control.

```
TextBox txt_field = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[12].FindControl("txt_Comment");
```

Why don't you assign the textbox.text value to the GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[12].Text ?

Which will return a value assuming it exists.